# How to use regular expressions while searching in Papertrail app?

Tags: devops, papertrail-app

I want to search using a regular expression in the search bar of Papertrailapp.

When I try some thing like this

```
randomText \(\d\d\d
```

Expected result : randomText (223

Actual Result : No search found.

Any guidance on this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is Papertrailapp? give us a sample input string and your desired output!

Comment: For example I would like to find 5xx (Internal server error, Service unavailable, Bad gateway). What would be it's regular expression as "5\d\d" does not work. 
Papertrail app is a utility where you can search for string, patterns in your centralised log server. 
https://papertrailapp.com/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use Regex directly within log search.
See the search documentation [here](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/Success_Center/papertrail/Content/kb/how-it-works/search-syntax.htm).

However, you can use regex when creating re-usable log filters which, depending on your usage, may be what you're looking for. See [this documentation](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/Success_Center/papertrail/Content/kb/how-it-works/log-filtering.htm).